# How to add an exception error if record is not found in this code

Tags: c#, sql, windows-forms-designer

Hi guys as the tittle says how would i apply an error if no such record is found in this code below

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from CustTicket where CustmerContactNumber ='" + tbCcontact.Text.ToString() + "'";
        db.ExeNonQuery(cmd);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            tbTest.Text = dr["CustmerName"].ToString();
        }
     }
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve? show a message box to the user? basically, you would have to check for a condition like `dt.Rows.Count == 0`

Comment: What do you mean by "apply an error"? Throw exception?

Comment: ah yes, and because of the query composed with raw user input, the good old "safe for scripting" disclaimer [here](http://bobby-tables.com/csharp)

Comment: Sorry meant to show an error*

Comment: @DharyAlmousa Did you solve the problem? If yes then please accept the answer. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

You mean?

```
if (dt.Rows.Count == 0 )
{
    // Here you can throw new Exception(); or something like that
    MessageBox.Show("Some text", "Some title",  MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```